# checkbox validation for terms and conditions

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

While a user is registering for the login page, at the end he has to check the checkbox. When he clicks on the checkbox we must check whether user has clicked the terms and conditions page or not, If yes we should allow the user to continue, else we need to throw error.

Can I achieve in spring MVC?

```
<input type="checkbox"> Please click the <a href="#"> terms and conditions</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be easily done in javascript. On the submit click the just put a if else condition. If checkbox ischecked, perform submission else alert.